# Ionic and camel cased class names like SignInPage can not be found

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I've created a page with `ionic g page SignInPage` and in my main.ts I've added a check to verify if there is a storage (Ionic Storage) variable 'userLoggedIn' and depending on that the index page or the sign in page should be shown.

Right now I'm getting an error the SignInPage can not be found and `ionic serve` tells me `There are multiple entries in the deeplink config with the name of SignInPage`.

In `sign-in.ts` I've replaced `@IonicPage()` with `@IonicPage({ name: 'SignInPage'})` but this didn't help. (According to: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/there-are-multiple-entries-in-the-deeplink-config-with-the-segment-of-main-error-after-latest-update/107111)

I think I need to configure something for the camel casing? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have been a caching issue. After rerunning `ionic serve` it worked like I expected.